# Vim: f motion to accented char in US international

Tags: vim, find, motion

To find the next character one the line, one simply use the <kbd>f</kbd> key. It works well with standard char.
Say, for the following line:

> one line of text.

If I want to go to the first "t", I just type <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>.
However, for the following line:

> one line with accented character: à, é, ù.

I can't do <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> using a US international keyboard layout (with this layout, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> produces "é").
It seems the <kbd>'</kbd> escape the f motion (or try to find the "'" char in the line and then sends the "e" command).
How can I find an accented character?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't search enough...
The answer lies here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters

<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd>